# How to keep floated div from moving beneath other floated div when the browser width resizes?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm having a problem where a floated div moves beneath another floated div when the browser width resizes. I created an example of this behavior in a jsfiddle (below) in which I use dummy text and a dummy table. If you open the jsfiddle, and resize the width of the display area, you'll see that eventually the right hand div (the table) moves beneath the left hand div (the text).

https://jsfiddle.net/p7yr5t4u/23/

```
.view {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%; 
}

#A {
  width: 200px;
}
```

Ideally what I would like to see happen is for the right hand div to display a horizontal scrollbar when the browser width resizes, and for it to stay on the right hand side instead of moving beneath the left hand div. I tried setting "overflow-x: auto" on the div to no avail. How can I make a horizontal scrollbar appear in the table on the right instead of having it move beneath the text on the left?

I researched Stack Overflow for this problem and found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48804095/how-to-prevent-divs-from-going-underneath-floated-divs) as well as [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034098/right-floated-div-and-min-width-div-moves-to-the-new-line-on-browser-resize). The only solution I could glean is that float itself is a problem, and it's hard to get this desired behavior when divs are floated. Is there a way for me to get my desired result while keeping the float layout? Or is float itself the culprit?

Comment: Yes the float itself is the culprit .. removing the float will make it easy

Comment: @TemaniAfif Is there a way to do this while keeping float?

Comment: I don't think so .. by the way, why you need float? this is the real question

Comment: @TemaniAfif As a follow-up question, do you think using float is bad style? should it be avoided when possible?

Comment: I would avoid the word *bad*. Float is used to float elements so it depends on your situation. If you are using float to create your layout, you are probably doing it wrong and you need to think of better ways (flexbox, grid, inline-block, etc) but in some case you want the float behavior so you have to use it ... That's why I was asking if you really need float ... in this particular case, I don't see the need of float because what you want is to have two blocks side by side and this is a perfect use case of inline-block elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple fix is to convert float to `inline-block` and use `white-space:nowrap`:

```css
.container {
 white-space:nowrap;
}
.view {
  white-space:normal;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

#A {
  width: 200px;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div id="A" class="view">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>

  <div id="B" class="view">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It looks like this solution may have worked! One question: why do we need to set the white-space property (in both the container and the view)?

Comment: @ktm5124 because of inheritance ... you should put back the white-space to normal in the inner container, remove it and you will see the *bad* effect

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll wait a bit before I accept but it seems like your solution works.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind one additional wrapper under #B and you really want to use floats, you can do it like this. I took those 200px of #A as a “constant” since you used it in your example.

```css
.view {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

#A {
  width: 200px;
}

#B {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: -200px;
  padding-left: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
#C {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<div>

<div id="A" class="view">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>

<div id="B" class="view">
<div id="C">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: but the table will shrink here and we won't have scroll

Comment: Yes, it will shrink until a point it can't any more and that's when the scroll kicks in.